# OpenCV: How to find individual positions of connected letters in an image?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have an image of text that I would like to segment so I can get the individual positions of the letters. However, some of the letters are touching each other, so I'm having trouble with segmentation:

[image]

I tried using some contour methods (which seem to work for license plates, etc), but it always ends up detecting the entire block of text. I also tried to apply some erosion to increase the gaps between the letters, but sometimes this causes parts of the letters to erode while the connections remain. I also tried blurring the image and then thresholding, but like before, the connections remain. Is there a way to get the positions of these letters?

Comment: do you know how many letters are present?

Comment: I don't, but I think I can estimate by training some regressors. If I did, is there a method that works with that information?

Comment: I dont know, but it could probably help.

Comment: The [watershed](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_watershed/py_watershed.html#watershed) segmentation can give you ideas. Maybe finding the center of the letter can help.